# Jquery image blur effect with in a div?

Tags: jquery, image, effects, blur

Consider i have `three images` and `one bannerDiv`.... On initial page load i should show the first image and after sometimeout say `300ms` i must show the second image and vise versa....
I have to `blur` the first image and show second image .... Any suggestion how it can be done with jquery...

```
<div Id="BannerDiv">
<img src="mylocation" alt="image1"/>
<img src="mylocation" alt="image2"/>
<img src="mylocation" alt="image3"/>
</div>
```

and my jquery function is,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

         $(document).ready(function() {
     //how to show first image and blur it to show second image after 300 ms
          });
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

1st image to fade out after `300ms` and show 2nd image
2nd image to fade out after `300ms` and show 3rd image
3rd image to fade out after `300ms` and show 1st image....

**Second EDIT:**

I used nick's but nothing happening..

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
       <div Id="BannerDiv">
            <img src="Images/banner3.jpg" alt="image1" width="954" height="327"/>
            <img src="Images/ban_main_25.jpg" alt="image2" width="954" height="327"/>
            <img src="Images/banner_25.jpg" alt="image3" width="954" height="327"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#BannerDiv > :first').show();
            setTimeout(rotate, 1000);
        });

        function rotate() {
            var c = $('#BannerDiv > :visible').css({ 'z-index': 2 }).fadeOut(2000, function() {
                setTimeout(rotate, 300);
            }).next().css({ 'z-index': 1 }).show();
            if (c.length == 0) $('#BannerDiv > :first').css({ 'z-index': 1 }).show();
        }
     </script>
    </form>
</body>
```

And css

```
 #BannerDiv {width: 954px; height: 327px;}
 #BannerDiv img {position: absolute; width: 954px; height: 327px; display: none;}​
```

Comment: @Nick fadein and fadeout effects

Comment: Why do you have the images commented out? `<%--`

The CSS is `#BannerDiv img` as well, not div (as in my answer) for your use :)

Comment: @Nick i ll edit it for you...

Comment: @bala - You also need to remove the `style="display:none;"` from the `BannerDiv` element, otherwise everything's hidden.

Comment: @Nick it works pretty well but all the three images are coming.... 123 blur, and 231 blur, and 312 blur... But it should be 1 and blur, 2 and blur, 3...

Comment: @bala3569 - You're only giving each element **.3 seconds** to show, I'd increase the that quite a bit.

Comment: @Nick can you edit it in your answer for me..

Comment: @bala3569 - Edited, just change that `300` to `3000` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick way to do it:

```
$(function() {
    $('#BannerDiv > :first').show();
    setTimeout(rotate, 1000);
});

function rotate() {
  var c = $('#BannerDiv > :visible').css({ 'z-index': 2 }).fadeOut(2000, function() {
    setTimeout(rotate, 3000);
  }).next().css({ 'z-index': 1 }).show();
  if(c.length == 0) $('#BannerDiv > :first').css({ 'z-index': 1 }).show();
}
​
```

You'd need the following CSS to match (adjust dimensions to yours):

```
#BannerDiv {width: 400px; height: 200px;}
#BannerDiv img {position: absolute; width: 400px; height: 200px; display: none;}​
```

[Here's an example using colored divs, it would be the exact same when replaced with images like you want](http://jsfiddle.net/23T5K/2/).

Comment: @bala3569 - With the `#BannerDiv img` CSS that shouldn't be happening, do you have a link to your page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) for a repeated timed action:

```
$(function() {
  setInterval(300, cycle_images);
});

function cycle_images() {
  var banner = $("#BannerDiv");
  if (banner.is(":hidden")) {
    banner.children().hide().end().show();
  }
  var images = banner.children("img");
  var visible = images.filter(":visible");
  var index = images.index(visible);
  var next = (index + 1) % images.length;
  visible.fadeOut(100, function() {
    images[next].fadeIn(100);
  });
}
```

As for whether to hide the banner and/or images with CSS (external or inline), my personal opinion is that it is generally better to do it this way because if you don't it can result in a noticeable flicker if the `ready()` event is delayed for any reason.

Comment: @cletus error `useless setInterval call (missing quotes around argument?)` when i used the above function..

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($){
$.fn.showdelay = function(){
    var delay = 0;
    return this.each(function(){
        $(this).delay(delay).fadeIn(100);
        delay += 300;
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

Usage: `$("#BannerDiv").children().showdelay();`

maybe a little more elegant.

Comment: It only cycles through all the elements once.